# Custom Gson serializer with fields that are unknown at runtime

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm attempting to do custom Gson serialization to create a Json object to send to a service except their are some fields that are not known at runtime.

The json I wish to create should look something like this:

```
{
    "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP",
    "attributes": {
        "FirstName": [
            {
                "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP/attributes/FirstName",
                "value": "Michael"
            }
        ]

    },
    "crosswalks": [
        {
            "type": "configuration/sources/AMA",
            "value": "10000012"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to successfully create this json using Gson, but the issue is that I have thousands of fields that could be under the attributes object, in this example there is only the `FirstName` but if I was doing a create there would be as many attributes as that person, place or thing had associated with them.

Because currently I am able to create this using Gson by having 4 different classes:

1. Type
2. Attributes
3. FirstName
4. Crosswalks

But I want to be able to have FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, etc. all underneath the attributes object without creating an individual java class for all of them. The json would look like this in that case:

```
{
    "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP",
    "attributes": {
        "FirstName": [
            {
                "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP/attributes/FirstName",
                "value": "Doe"
            }
        ],
        "LastName": [
            {
                "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP/attributes/LastName",
                "value": "John"
            }
        ],
        "MiddleName": [
            {
                "type": "configuration/entityTypes/HCP/attributes/MiddleName",
                "value": "Michael"
            }
        ]

    },
    "crosswalks": [
        {
            "type": "configuration/sources/AMA",
            "value": "10000012"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use Gson to create the attributes object without creating java objects for all of the different attributes I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, Object>` where `Object` will be an one-element-array. See, for example, below model:

```
class Attributes {

    private Map<String, Object> attributes;

    // getters, setters
}

class Type {

    private final String type;
    private final String value;

    public Type(String type, String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Now, let's build `attributes` manually:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("FirstName", Collections.singletonList(new Type("url/FirstName", "Rick")));
        map.put("LastName", Collections.singletonList(new Type("url/LastName", "Pickle")));

        Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
        attributes.setAttributes(map);

        String json = new Gson().newBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(attributes);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "FirstName": [
      {
        "type": "url/FirstName",
        "value": "Rick"
      }
    ],
    "LastName": [
      {
        "type": "url/LastName",
        "value": "Pickle"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```